# Como configurar Log4j2 com Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

Por favor observem o estrutura do meu projeto e tentam enxergar aonde está o meu arquivo log4j2.xml

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu configurei dessa forma;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora observe a linha 13 do arquivo log4j2.xml

Essa linha tem o objetivo que quando o projeto fizer uma gravação em banco de dados ele emita um log de SQL no consoles do eclipse para informar que ouve uma inserção, porém não é isso que está acontecendo, atualmente quando eu gravo informações no banco ele não mostra nada no consoles do eclipse. Eu estou usando o FramWorks Spring Boot, eu faço no Spring MVC e funcionar normalmente, eu estou achando que pode ser problema de artefato ou problema de alguma configuração que precise realizar no Spring Boot.

Eu sei que eu posso realizar essa configuração no arquivo **application.properties**  , mas meu objetivo mesmo é realizar as configurações no log4j2

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Já tentei realizar essas tentativas

Eu troquei os artefatos desse

```
<!-- Logging -->
<log4j.version>2.6</log4j.version>
<jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.21</jcl-over-slf4j.version>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>${log4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${jcl-over-slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Por esse;

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Porém não resolveu.

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Alguém tem como me ajudar?

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que eu entendi do teu problema seria que tu quer logar o hibernate.

O próprio Hibernate tem uma config para isso, eu achei este post no stakoverflow que pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536829/hibernate-show-real-sql

Porque se eu não me engano o Hibernate tem um property que tu bota pra true e ele log o sql que ele usa.

E neste link demonstra outro maneira para configurar, https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/
nele o Myong bota o log level do hibernate para INFO, tu já tentou isto?